# Two Views in 1 view controller

Tags: iphone

Basically, what I am trying to do is I have my TestViewController and there are 2 views under it, the first view will start with a tool bar and 2 buttons, one for imagepicker and the other one for mail sending, I am already done with that, and after pick the image from the photo library, the second view will be popped out(I want to do some image editing here) with a tool bar and 1 button back to the first view. I am doing something like [self.view addSubview:2ndview], and it works, but when I am trying to use -(IBAction)dismissDrawing:{[2ndview removeFromSuperview] }the program just shut down.
Can anyone help me? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: is 2ndview an instance variable? sounds like your over releasing it

Comment: Yes, it is an instance variable in the TestViewController, and I declare this view and its method in another file called DrawView.h/m so what do you mean by over releasing it? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at my sample application I did last year.](http://github.com/computermatt/25-Apps-in-Aug/tree/master/multi-light/) Basically you need a view that will act like a superview, then add views on top of it (if I remember correctly, it's been a while since I did it that way, now I just use multiple xibs).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do would be better suited to a modal view.
See [Human Interface Guidelines - Modal Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ModalViews/ModalViews.html)

Instead of adding a subview, try

```
[self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Then in the dismissDrawing you can use

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```